# Setting the selected model of a Backbone collection - who observes what?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, event-handling

I have a `Backbone.Collection` with some `Backbone.Model`s displayed in a list that should function like a single `select`. Specifically, I have the following:

- A map view, with each model displayed as a marker
- A map popup, with the selected model displayed in a bubble
- An info view, with the selected model displayed in a `div`

In other words, I need to be able to 1) ensure only the last selected item is visually selected with class `active` applied as a result, and 2) ensure observers receive the `change` notification and the latest model.

I'm having unexpected difficulty implementing this **cleanly**. I mean, it works, but I can tell that the `change` event is firing twice. I think I'm just having a major brain shart - because I cannot seem to think of a way to manage the `selected` attribute of the *old* selection without triggering the `change` event on the observer (the view).

I can post code, but I don't think that is necessary. What would be helpful is to know:

- Should each model's selected property be directly tied to the view, or managed by the collection?
- Is it possible to implement this without creating another state-like property of the collection, ie `selectedModel` ?

Comment: Did you consider having a "State" model that behaves as the application state and contains the "active" model id at any given time? This could decouple your logic and make things clear (e.g, collection holds data, "state model" holds state)

Comment: Where would the `State` live?